# How to search in all fields in ElasticSearch index?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

```
{"cf_items":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"properties":{"CFDocumentURI":{"properties":{"identifier":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"title":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"uri":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"CFItemType":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"CFItemTypeURI":{"properties":{"identifier":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"title":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"uri":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"educationLevel":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"fullStatement":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"humanCodingScheme":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"identifier":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"lastChangeDateTime":{"type":"date"},"uri":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"routing":{"allocation":{"include":{"_tier_preference":"data_content"}}},"number_of_shards":"1","provided_name":"cf_items","creation_date":"1654520558130","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"wMIBuI59QoWhR2-p69ER8Q","version":{"created":"7130099"}}}}}
```

and I want to search inside any field with matching keyword? How can I do that?

I tried below way

```
array:2 [
    "index" => "cfitems-*"
    "body" => array:1 [
        "query" => array:1 [
        "bool" => array:1 [
            "should" => array:1 [
            0 => array:1 [
                "match_all" => array:1 [
                0 => "Default"
                ]
            ]
            ]
        ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query":    "Will Smith",
            "fields": ["*"] // for all fields or pass in specific fields 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this possible to search without search term or null search term?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you have many fields in your index. you can use the [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query which also supports the wildcard in the fields name.

[Refer fields with wildcard example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#field-boost) from official Elasticsearch document.